# Can I maintain a Vec of TcpStreams to write to them across threads whenever one of them reads a new input?

Tags: tcp, rust, tcpserver

I want to do message broadcasting: when one of the clients sends a message, the server writes it to each socket. My main problem is I can't figure out how to send the `Vec` to the threads. I can't use `Mutex` because that will lock the access of other threads to the `Vec` for reading. I can't clone and send because `TcpStream` can't  be cloned and sent. Here's my attempt until now

```
use std::net::{TcpStream, TcpListener};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};
use std::cell::RefCell;

type StreamSet = Arc<RefCell<Vec<TcpStream>>>;
type StreamReceiver = Arc<Mutex<Receiver<StreamSet>>>;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:8000").unwrap();
    let mut connection_set: StreamSet = Arc::new(RefCell::new(vec![]));
    let mut id = 0;
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    let rx = Arc::new(Mutex::new(rx));
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let receiver = rx.clone();
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        (*connection_set).borrow_mut().push(stream);
        println!("A connection established with client {}", id);
        thread::spawn(move || handle_connection(receiver, id));
        id += 1;
        tx.send(connection_set.clone()).unwrap();
    }

}

fn handle_connection(rx: StreamReceiver, id: usize) {
    let streams;
    {
        streams = *(rx.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap()).borrow();
    }
    let mut connection = &streams[id];
    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 512];
        if let Err(_) = connection.read(&mut buffer) {
            break;
        };
        println!("Request: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]));
        if let Err(_) = connection.write(&buffer[..]) {
            break;
        };
        if let Err(_) = connection.flush() {
            break;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea is to spawn a single "controller" thread **and** a thread for every socket. Each thread would own the socket and have a channel to send data back to the controller. The controller would own a `Vec` of channels to send to each thread. When a thread receives data, you send it to the controller which duplicates it and sends it back to each worker thread. You can wrap the data in an `Arc` to prevent unneeded duplication, and you should provide an ID to avoid echoing the data back to the original sender (if you need to).

This moves the ownership completely within a single thread, which should avoid the issues you are experiencing.

You may also wish to look into [Tokio](https://tokio.rs/), which should allow you to do something similar but without the need to spawn threads in a 1-1 mapping.

> I can't use `Mutex` because that will lock the access of other threads

You can always try a different locking mechanism such as a [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html).

> because `TcpStream` can't be cloned

Sure it can: [`TcpStream::try_clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone).

Comment: Ah thanks. I am actually kinda newish to coding, will complete a year next month. So I was trying to implement it on my own as much as I can before using an abstraction like tokio, so I understand what's going on under the hood. I will try implementing the controller worker model. Will each seperate thread have a seperate channel or will they use the same receiver, sender pair?

Comment: I'd expect that the controller thread to have one unique channel per worker thread to send data to them, then a reused channel from each worker back to the controller (since they are **m**ultiple **p**roducer, **s**ingle **c**onsumer channels). In total, there should be N + 1 channels.

Comment: Ah okay. Makes sense. Thanks.